# Problem with solving the task related to operating on incidents in service now

Tags: servicenow

I am new to service now and have a problem with how to do two tasks.
what is 1. it seems to me that it should be done using business roles, but I don't know what script to use here ... I blocked.

In the second case, I don't know where to start. Can someone help?

1. As an itil user, I should be able to move an incident to an On Hold state and specify a Date/Time. When this Date/Time is reached, the incident state should change to Update Required. This is so I am reminded that an incident I was working on requires my attention.
2. As an itil user, I should not be able to select a priority for an incident that is lower priority than any of its children.

If I select a priority for a child incident that is higher than its parent, then I should receive a warning on submit. If I choose to submit anyway, then the parent incident’s priority should be updated to match the child’s.

Answer (score 0):

1. In my opinion you should consider using SLAs to achieve this requirement. However If you want to achieve It by using BR, you need to hold "the specific date" on Incident table by creating a custom date field. Then you could run the below after BR

var tdy = new GlideDate();

var dt = current.<custom_field_name> ;

if (tdy == dt) {

current.state = 3 // backend value of "On Hold" state

current.update() ;

}

2. You could use BR again like below on Incident table

var myVar = current.priority ;

var prt = parent.priority ;

if (myVar < prt) {

gs.gs.addErrorMessage("Your message");

current.priority = parent.priority ;

current.update();

}